# PyQt5 проблемы с заполеннием tablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtablewidget

*Что нужно* ? - Заполнить таблицу данными которые выдает БазаДанных.

В каком формате приходят данные:

```
[(25, 1, '1600', '05.01', '2021-01-03 11:59:08'), 
 (25, 3, '1130',    '06.01', '2021-01-03 10:25:08')]  #Тут две строчки до заполнения
```

Что по коду?:

*Сама таблица из которой беру информацию:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Сама структура БД и таблиц:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ФАЙЛ main.py - запрос на БД и сама обработка информации:

```
get_info = get_user_reg_info(request_id)  # запрос на бд: возврат выше("в каком формате приходят данные")
        self.data_processing(get_info) # вызов функции для обработки и заполенния таблицы



    def data_processing(self, get_info):  #попытка моих наработок, результат на скриншоте ниже
        print(get_info)
        row = 0
        for tup in get_info:
            col = 0

            for item in tup:
                cellinfo = QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, cellinfo)
                col += 1

            row += 1
```

[image: Результаты моих тестов]

*PS. Если что-то нужно ещё могу обновить, надеюсь вопрос понятен и информацию предоставил корректно.*

**UPDATED:** В чём ошибка, что заполняется всё почти правильно, кроме user_id & tsnap№, они почему-то пропускаються.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения быстрых и правильных ответов всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

> QTableWidgetItem::QTableWidgetItem(const QString &text, int type = Type)
>
> Создает элемент таблицы с заданным текстом.

Попробуйте заменить строку:

```
cellinfo = QTableWidgetItem(item)
```

на строку:

```
cellinfo = QTableWidgetItem(str(item))
```

Comment: Всё работает. Спасибо!!!